# Has there ever been a "light" weapon other than the lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, weapon

Has there ever been a human-usable "light" weapon other than the lightsaber?

For this question I am **not** interested in weapons that resemble swords, double ended or not.  I've seen plenty of them, and even if they are really cool...

[image: So not this, as cool as it is]

...I was wondering if Kyber Crystals had ever been used to create other weaponry.  I am interested in whether there has been a light axe / light whip / light spear or anything similar.

I know that Kyber Crystals are used in the making of lightsabers, and I think they were also used in the planet killing laser in the Deathstar.  With this in mind, have Kyber Crystals been used to ever create something like a gun or rifle that can be used by a person?

So I am looking to see if a "light" weapon was ever made that fits these criteria:

- Doesn't resemble a sword
- Must be usable by a human (or equivalent)
- Can be a close combat or ranged weapon
- **Exists in the current canon** (Not in StarWars Legends / Expanded Universe)

And if Kyber Crystal were never used for anything other than lightsabers and Deathstar lasers, was there any reason given why the use of Kyber Crystals was limited to these specific designs?

Comment: Does a [Sith army knife](http://shirtoid.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/sith-army-knife.jpg) count?

Comment: @Voronwë haha! only if its canon ;)

Comment: Sure.  There are blasters that shoot light bullets.

Comment: @b_jonas I am looking for the weapon of a Jedi Knight. Not a clumsy or random blaster; but an elegant weapon for a more civilized age (that isn't based on a sword).

Comment: @phantom42 This question was asked before Star Wars: The Force Awakens came out, and the Star Wars canon has since changed - I was hoping for an answer that fits to the current canon

Comment: Well, I don't recall Rogue One or Rebels introducing anything new since TFA came out, and those are the only additions to Disney Canon that I know of. The Last Jedi might change things, but 1) That's not very likely and 2) That's not until December this year.

Comment: The questions are the same though. If you'd like more current answers, you can also add a bounty and set the reason as "current answers are outdated".